# SSM Document not working LAMBDA -> SSM- > Event bridge , im stuck and out of ideas

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

So I've tried setting up a LAMBDA function using python 3.9, which calls my SSM Document which will restart "Coldfusion 2018 application server" within windows, if the cloudwatch alert name is triggered. I have it set in eventbridge to alarm state change which means everything the domain goes down "Coldfusion service stopped" it should run the SSM document and the powershell script. But nothing is working at all and ive tried practically everything i know of.

Below are my default roles for LAMBDA + Inline Policy, along with my LAMBDA function, my SSM document and my eventbridge.

**My Lambda default role assigned is :**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-2:727665054500:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-2:727665054500:log-group:/aws/lambda/johntest:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**And my Inline policy attached to my default role,  to allow SSM is:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:SendCommand",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Lambda function:**

```py
import os
import boto3
import json 

ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  InstanceId = 'i-06692c60000c89460'
  ssmDocument = 'johntest'
  log_group = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME']
  
  targetInstances = [InstanceId]
  response = ssm.send_command(
    InstanceIds=targetInstances,
    DocumentName=ssmDocument,
    DocumentVersion='$DEFAULT',
    CloudWatchOutputConfig={
                  'CloudWatchLogGroupName': log_group,
                  'CloudWatchOutputEnabled': True
              }
  )
```

**EventBridge (CloudWatch events) which is the trigger for lambda**

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.cloudwatch"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "CloudWatch Alarm State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "alarmName": [
      "TASS-john2-Testing-SiteDown for domain https://johntest.tassdev.cloud/tassweb"
    ],
    "state": {
      "value": [
        "ALARM"
      ]
    },
    "previousState": {
      "value": [
        "OK"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**SSM document to run the PowerShell script** In SSM when you create an initial document, I selected the command/session document which may be wrong? Do I need to make an automation document? If so can someone show me the correct code/syntax please?

```
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Example document"
parameters:
  Message:
    type: "String"
    description: "Example parameter"
    default: "Hello World"
mainSteps:
  - action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
    name: "example"
    inputs:
      timeoutSeconds: '600'
      runCommand:
      - Restart-Service -DisplayName "ColdFusion 2018 Application Server"
```

I tried setting up the lambda function, with my instance ID/SSM document name, and the trigger is event bridge, which is set to my CloudWatch alarm based on state change. I cannot get the SSM document to trigger my window service "coldfusion" at all.

I have pasted my above code for the eventbridge/ssm document/lambda and even my default lambda role/inline policy which still doesn't seem to work. I also have the SSM agent installed on my instance but still nothing.

EDIT: Just went to Systems Manager, and clicked run command and it ran the powershell script and started up the coldfusion service, but why isn't it triggering from the CloudWatch alarm?

Cheers.

Comment: Hi,
Have you tried testing your lambda just to see if the SSM document get triggered?

Comment: Did you create event bridge rule for trigger?